# OpenVPN Timeout Error (WSAETIMEDOUT) (code=10060)

Tags: 16.04, openvpn

Output:
https://pastebin.com/EX1ThxRY

Here is my server config:
https://pastebin.com/NEqxV9uM

Here is my client config:
https://pastebin.com/Knih723t

Not really sure why this is happening, please help. I know for sure that my firewall is good.

Comment: The files on pastebin will go away, which renders the question and answers useless for future users.

Comment: When you look in the server config, there's an entry `verb 3` and a comment above, saying ># 5 and 6 can help to debug connection problems

Comment: Have you tried other ports than 443? I remember having problems building an OpenVPN over https ports. Have you checked your firewalls?

Comment: Yes, I've been trying dozens of ports.